# What are the smart ways to check if two files are same?

Tags: file, file-io, operating-system, checksum

I am looking for smart and efficient ways that will check if two files are completely same.

The program will loop all the folders recursively and they may include very large files.

So I decided to use incremental checks

### While looping:

1. Get all the file sizes, put them into a database entry with the associated file path.
2. When a size match is found, do `md5 hash check` to decide.
3. Finalize and do whatever necessary.

This would pretty much do it already. But, I wonder what are the other options that would sufficiently fast?

Answer (score 1):

I can not think of many other options available to you.

Remember that the md5 hash check (or any other calculation) is really only useful if you have a pre-existing md5 hash check (or some other calcuation) and you want to be reasonably assured that the file has not changed since your pre-existing calculation was last done.

Other things to use for reasonable assurity (using pre-existing calculations) are ...

```
1.  Inode and mount point IDs from the stat() family.
2.  mtime comparisons for info on when the file was last modified.
```

Otherwise, you are left with doing a straight byte-by-byte comparison between two files.

Comment: hash checks will be the fallback method always, i'll check the 1st option but mtime actually does not really say if the two are same. e.g. i may have downloaded the same iso file in different times but mtime will false report on that as if the files were different.

Comment: @fastreload: When using hash checks (because you have a hash value and a file) you are really checking if a file maps to the hash value.  If you have two files, using a hash is pointless if all you are interested is whether the files are the same--a straight byte comparison if faster.  You are correct about the mtime, though under a few special (limited) cases it can still prove useful which is why I included it.

Comment: byte-to-byte comparison is faster but it actually does not make a great difference because they are mostly io intensive processes, in hash checking, cpu will wait the io most of time to read and buffer; it will not make a great difference. yet hash-checking will be faster if there are more than 2 files which are same. i can put a md5 entry to the db, and for the 3rd match, i would only `read` 1 file, rather than reading both files. i cannot all the bytes to database, you know =)